# Retrospect always returning non fatal error "can't read security information, error -1012"

Tags: backup, network-share, retrospect

I use Retrospect every day to backup to a LTO3 Tape.

The Script in retrospect backs up a few folders both on the network and local HDD's. It backs up 2 network drives on 2 separate windows servers just fine but when it backs up a OSX Server 10.6 Network drive it gives the error.

```
18/04/2011 11:58:17 PM: Copying websites on Xservex5
File "\\XSERVEX5\websites\": can't read security information, error -1012 (feature unsupported)
```

The scripts use a network share login that has administrator access.

While the backup will still complete without problems it would be nice to do away with the daily emails at 2am....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the server didn't like hidden and .DS_STORE files over SMB/CIFS from the mac to windows. setup the mac server to backup using the retrospect client and it fixed the problem.